# ASP Textbox not updating, when to check PostBack?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

## The Problem

An `<asp:TextBox>` isn't updating.

### The Background

I have a page called `Add_Edit_Drugs.aspx`. This page can be accessed in one of two ways: the user can click on the `Add Drug` button, which fires the `Response.Redirect("Add_Edit_Drugs.aspx")` command. OR, they can click on a hyperlink, which sends them to the same page like this:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField
            DataNavigateUrlFields="Drug_INDEX"
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Add_Edit_Drugs.aspx?Drug_INDEX={0}"
            DataTextField="Drug_Name"
            HeaderText="Drug Name"
            />
```

The `Page_Load` event checks for the presence of a query string, and if it's there, it populates the fields with the information in the database, otherwise it just leaves them blank:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["Drug_INDEX"] != null)
    {
        String sIndex = Request.QueryString["Drug_INDEX"].ToString();

        if (!Int32.TryParse(sIndex, out Drug_INDEX)) //Query String not a valid index
        {
            errorMessage.Text = "There was an error retrieving the record.";
            message.Text = "Please contact you IT administrator.";
        }
        else
        {

            Drug_IO dio = new Drug_IO();
            SqlDataReader drugDataReader = dio.Get_Drug(Drug_INDEX);
            if (drugDataReader.Read())
            {
                drugNameTxt.Text = drugDataReader["Drug_Name"].ToString();
                descriptionTxt.Text = drugDataReader["DrugDescription"].ToString();
                toxTxt.Text = drugDataReader["Toxicity"].ToString();
                hlTxt.Text = drugDataReader["HalfLife"].ToString();
                hlUnitsTxt.Text = drugDataReader["HalfLife_Units"].ToString();
                bindingTxt.Text = drugDataReader["ProteinBinding"].ToString();
                logPTxt.Text = drugDataReader["LogP"].ToString();
                molecularWeightTxt.Text = drugDataReader["MolecularWeight"].ToString();
                molecularFormTxt.Text = drugDataReader["MolecularFormula"].ToString();
                chemicalForumlaTxt.Text = drugDataReader["ChemicalFormula"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have my `saveBtn_Click` method:

```
protected void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double halfLife;
    if (!Double.TryParse(hlTxt.Text, out halfLife))
        halfLife = Double.NaN;

    double logP;
    if (!Double.TryParse(logPTxt.Text, out logP))
        logP = Double.NaN;

    double moleWeight;
    if (!Double.TryParse(molecularWeightTxt.Text, out moleWeight))
        moleWeight = Double.NaN;

    if (-1 == Drug_INDEX) // New record to be inserted
    {
        Drug_Record dr = new Drug_Record(
            drugNameTxt.Text,
            descriptionTxt.Text,
            toxTxt.Text,
            halfLife,
            hlUnitsTxt.Text,
            bindingTxt.Text,
            logP,
            moleWeight,
            molecularFormTxt.Text,
            chemicalForumlaTxt.Text);

        if (dr.saveToDataBase())
        {
            Response.Redirect("List_Drugs.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            message.Text = "An error occured saving the record.";
            errorMessage.Text = "Please contact your system admin.";
        }
    }
    else //record already exists in db, needs to be updated
    {
        Drug_Record dr = new Drug_Record(
            drugNameTxt.Text,
            descriptionTxt.Text,
            toxTxt.Text,
            halfLife,
            hlUnitsTxt.Text,
            bindingTxt.Text,
            logP,
            moleWeight,
            molecularFormTxt.Text,
            chemicalForumlaTxt.Text,
            Drug_INDEX);

        if (dr.updateRecord())
        {
            Response.Redirect("List_Drugs.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            message.Text = "An error occur updating the record.";
            errorMessage.Text = "Please contact your system admin.";
        }
    }
}
```

Now, as I'm sure you've guessed, in my `else //record already exists` block, when I get the (supposedly) new values from the user edit, what I actually get is the original information which was retrieved from the database. I know from what I've read that the problem lies in the issue of whether or not `Page.IsPostBack`. I checked in `Page_Load`. I checked in `saveBtn_Click`. I checked before creating a new record, I checked before updating a record. I combined all those things. I inverted them. No matter what I've tried, one of two things happens:

1. I get the old information.
2. Nothing.

This specific problem is really a symptom of a larger problem - I (kinda) understand what a `PostBack` *is*, but don't really understand what *causes* it. In this instance, what causes a PostBack, and when do I need to check for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your page load you should check to see if it is a postback using `Page.IsPostBack` if it is not a postback then you should do your initial loading of the page. If it is a postback then one of the controls on the page has initiated a server side event, such as a button click.

In your button click you can update the labels or textboxes. The page load will be called on every postback, so make sure you don't run initialization code twice.

It looks like your page load is running the initialization for every postback, when you only want to run it on the initial load. Try this modification:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {

        if (Request.QueryString["Drug_INDEX"] != null)
        {
            String sIndex = Request.QueryString["Drug_INDEX"].ToString();

            if (!Int32.TryParse(sIndex, out Drug_INDEX)) //Query String not a valid index
            {
                errorMessage.Text = "There was an error retrieving the record.";
                message.Text = "Please contact you IT administrator.";
            }
            else
            {

                Drug_IO dio = new Drug_IO();
                SqlDataReader drugDataReader = dio.Get_Drug(Drug_INDEX);
                if (drugDataReader.Read())
                {
                    drugNameTxt.Text = drugDataReader["Drug_Name"].ToString();
                    descriptionTxt.Text = drugDataReader["DrugDescription"].ToString();
                    toxTxt.Text = drugDataReader["Toxicity"].ToString();
                    hlTxt.Text = drugDataReader["HalfLife"].ToString();
                    hlUnitsTxt.Text = drugDataReader["HalfLife_Units"].ToString();
                    bindingTxt.Text = drugDataReader["ProteinBinding"].ToString();
                    logPTxt.Text = drugDataReader["LogP"].ToString();
                    molecularWeightTxt.Text = drugDataReader["MolecularWeight"].ToString();
                    molecularFormTxt.Text = drugDataReader["MolecularFormula"].ToString();
                    chemicalForumlaTxt.Text = drugDataReader["ChemicalFormula"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now what happens is that when a PostBack happens, it will not run the initialization code and it will continue on to your button click event where you can update the value of the your textbox. PageLoad is really the only place you need to check to see if it is a postback in this situation, since button events can only be triggered by a postback.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the page load is a postback before first initialization of  the form.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack && Request.QueryString["Drug_INDEX"] != null)
```

I'd also suggest reading up on how the asp.net page lifecycle works.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes exactly you have PostBack problem, when you load data for the first time, you must place in the ! IsPostback.

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
   //First Load
   //Initialize Data
    if (Request.QueryString["Drug_INDEX"] != null)
    {
       ........

    }
}
```

When you click Button, you post your datas => (IsPostBack == true) =>    (! IsPostBack == false) 
=> He don't pass by this phase of initialize